# Print the raw value of a column alone, in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ { 'name': 'george', 'age': 23 }, {'name': 'anna', 'age': 26}])
```

Now I want to retrive George's age:

```
df[df.name == 'george'].age
```

But this outputs some extra information along with the raw value:

```
0    23
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

How do I just get it to print `23`?

Comment: `int(df[df.name == 'george'].age)`? `df[df.name == 'george'].age.values[0]`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) for converting `Serie` to `numpy array` and then select first value by `[0]`:

```
print (df.loc[df.name == 'george', 'age'].values)
[23]
print (df.loc[df.name == 'george', 'age'].values[0])
23
```

Or simply select first value of `Series` with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (df.loc[df.name == 'george', 'age'].iloc[0])
23
```

Or select first item by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
print (df.loc[df.name == 'george', 'age'].iat[0])
23
```

Or use [`Series.item`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.item.html):

```
print (df.loc[df.name == 'george', 'age'].item())
23
```

---

If possible no match value, above solutions failed.

Then is possible use `next` with `iter` trick:

```
print (next(iter(df.loc[df.name == 'george', 'age']),'no match value'))
23

print (next(iter(df.loc[df.name == 'jano z hornej dolnej', 'age']),'no match value'))
no match value
```

Answer (score 2):

Might as well make my comment an answer:

```
df[df.name == 'george'].age.values[0]
```

or

```
int(df[df.name == 'george'].age)
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```
df = [ { 'name': 'george', 'age': 23 }, {'name': 'anna', 'age': 26}]
k = [x['age'] for x in df if x['name'] == 'george']
print k
```